# How to upload large files through filestack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, request, filestack

When I try to upload a large file (+5GB) with the client.upload function of filestack-js in nodejs it throws an error:

`RangeError: File size is greater than possible Buffer: 0x7fffffff bytes`

I was using this SDK because I read that this allows to upload a large files through chunks but if I can't use it, what else can I use for upload this type of files? Anyone has an idea what I can use for upload large files with Filestack?

Comment: What is your chunk size?
Is this smaller than equal to the allowed request size by your backend server?

Comment: this problem is about the sdk function `upload` from filestack-js, it uses `fs.read` for read the file like a buffer but the file size is greater than 5GB, I'm not sure how I can upload this type of file with filestack because even their sdk doesn't work.